# Reverse individual words in a Java String

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse text in a given string. The problem I am having with my code below is that when I enter something like **"Hey man"** it prints out **"nam yeH"** Whereas I want it to print out **"yeH nam"**. Is there any help you could give me that could fix this mistake?

Thanks so much in advance!

```
public class ReverseWords {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String text;


    text = IO.readString();

    int plusIndex = text.indexOf("+");

    if ( plusIndex != -1 ) {

        IO.reportBadInput();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    IO.outputStringAnswer(new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString());


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the input on the space character, then loop through the array of words, reverse them, and piece them back into a new string.

```
private String reverseWords(String text) {
  String result = "";
  String[] words = text.split(" ");
  StringBuilder builder;
  for (String word : words) {
    builder = new StringBuilder(word);
    result = result + " " +  builder.reverse().toString();
  )
  return result.replaceFirst(" ", "");
}
reverseWords("hey man");  //should return "yeh nam"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringTokenizer to tokenize words, and then reverse word by word, and sum it up in a String by adding missing blanks.
Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hey man";

    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(s).reverse());

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        sb.append(new StringBuilder(st.nextToken()).reverse());
        if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```